# Replace value of given index using GArray of glib-library

Tags: c, arrays, glib

Using GArray of the glib library I want to set the value at position x to a given value. Just like i do using c-array and array[x]=5;

Why can't I find any function to do so? Isn't this the meaning of an arrays? Documentation: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html

I could remove the old value and insert the new one. But this is kind of stupid. Is there a better way?

**UPDATE:**

On Gnome Bugzilla it was explaint to me this is the usual way:

```
int *element = &g_array_index (array, int, i);
*element = 42;
```

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=764599

Comment: Have you tried `g_array_insert_val`?

Comment: yes, but this inserts the value. I want to replace it. Like I told - i could insert the new value and delete the old value - but isn't there a faster and more efficient way than copying every value 2 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation does not make this clear, but because `g_array_index` is a macro you can use it to set as well as get.

```
g_array_index(foo, int, 0) = 23;
g_array_index(foo, int, 1) = 42;
```

Unfortunately it **does not update nor check the size of the array** kinda defeating the point of GArray.  You'll either have to use `g_array_sized_new` or `g_array_set_size` to ensure there is enough allocated memory.

I cannot find documentation nor an example of this. It should be documented beyond the vague mention in the [description](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html#glib-Arrays.description) that you can use `g_array_index` to "access an element", but that's later contradicted by the [`g_array_index` docs](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html#g-array-index) which says that it only "returns the element".  Even better would be to provide `g_array_set_val` and have no confusion. [Perhaps you can let them know](https://developer.gnome.org/about/feedback.html.en)?